# preventDefault. Wait for menu animation before go to link

Tags: jquery

Hello guys I have problems with my code. I trying to wait for some classes before re-direct to menu page. I using preventDefault. It is not working. Or how could I do test alert after my menu is closed. I have tested my selectors.

Now when I clicking on link it goes nowhere... :)

```
`$('.menu-item a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.menu-item').addClass('menu-trigger', function(){
      window.location = href; 
    });
});`
```

And my HTML code.
Maybe problem is that href links going from WP?

```
<div class="menu-nasicomy-menu-container">
<ul id="super-set-menu" class="primary-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1049" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1049"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-01/">Link 01</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1050" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1050"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-02/">Link 02</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1051" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1051"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-03/">Link 03</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1052" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1052"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-04/">Link 04</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1053" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1053"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-05/">Link 05</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1054" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1054"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-06/">Link 06</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML

Comment: So, I edited my main question.

Comment: Are you trying to make an animation before the browser go to the link destination?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're trying to add a class to do something like a fading transition  between pages, so thats the code i use in some projects. Usually i fade-out the body with a class.

```
$('.menu-item a').click(function(event) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.menu-item').addClass('menu-trigger');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href=href;
    }, 500); // this is the counter for the settimeout function
});
```

Comment: Rafael thanx. I solved my problem with your code example. Acctualy setTimeout function helps me to trigger menu closing animations.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `addClass` in wrong way, to call a function with `addClass` it takes only on parameter as a function `.addClass( function )`.

> A function returning one or more space-separated class names to be
>   added to the existing class name(s)

For more refer to `.addClass( function )` [Documntation](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/#addClass-function)

```js
$('.menu-item a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.menu-item').addClass(function() {
    window.location = href;
    return "menu-trigger";
  });

  alert("Still here");
});
```

```css
.menu-trigger {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-nasicomy-menu-container">
  <ul id="super-set-menu" class="primary-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1049" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1049"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-01/">Link 01</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1050" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1050"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-02/">Link 02</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1051" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1051"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-03/">Link 03</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1052" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1052"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-04/">Link 04</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1053" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1053"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-05/">Link 05</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1054" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1054"><a href="http://www.example.lt/Link-06/">Link 06</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Wael. It is usefull information for me to understand how preventDefault function works.